# How to PIVOT the next ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a temp table that is populated by this query:

```
SELECT  att.property, att.stayDate, att.addedTimeStamp, att.rowNumber
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  RIGHT('000' + CAST(att.property AS VARCHAR(4)),4) AS property,
            CAST(att.stay_date AS DATE) AS stayDate,
            CAST(added_timestamp AS DATETIME) AS addedTimeStamp,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY property, stay_date ORDER BY added_timestamp) AS rowNumber
        FROM dbo.tb_rm_portal_attention_days att
            WHERE att.revenue_initiative = 'Test'
    ) att
```

Which then gets me the following into the temp table:

```
property   stayDate     addedTimeStamp             rowNumber
0053       2020-03-20   2019-03-04 17:10:32.837    1
0053       2020-03-20   2019-03-05 17:10:29.480    2
0053       2020-03-20   2019-03-06 17:10:25.940    3
0053       2020-03-20   2019-03-07 17:10:21.930    4
0100       2020-03-25   2019-03-04 17:10:32.837    1
0100       2020-03-25   2019-03-05 17:10:29.480    2
0100       2020-03-25   2019-03-06 17:10:25.940    3
0100       2020-03-25   2019-03-07 17:10:21.930    4
```

Out of here I would like to have the `property`, `stayDate`, `addedTimeStamp`, and then the next `addedTimeStamp` in the group and if it is the max to just return NULL or whatever...not sure if that makes sense...

What my end goal is to essentially get the following out of that temp table:

```
property   stayDate      firstTimeStamp            secondTimeStamp
0053       2020-03-20    2019-03-04 17:10:32.837   2019-03-05 17:10:29.480
0053       2020-03-20    2019-03-05 17:10:29.480   2019-03-06 17:10:25.940
0053       2020-03-20    2019-03-06 17:10:25.940   2019-03-07 17:10:21.930
0053       2020-03-20    2019-03-06 17:10:25.940   NULL
0100       2020-03-25    2019-03-04 17:10:32.837   2019-03-05 17:10:29.480
0100       2020-03-25    2019-03-05 17:10:29.480   2019-03-06 17:10:25.940
0100       2020-03-25    2019-03-06 17:10:25.940   2019-03-07 17:10:21.930
0100       2020-03-25    2019-03-06 17:10:25.940   NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `lead()`, but you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(att.property AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) AS property,
       CAST(att.stay_date AS DATE) AS stayDate,
       CAST(added_timestamp AS DATETIME) AS firstTimeStamp,
       LEAD(added_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY property, stay_date ORDER BY added_timestamp) AS secondTimeStamp
FROM dbo.tb_rm_portal_attention_days att
WHERE att.revenue_initiative = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example to use the [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function

```
LEAD(firstTimeStamp) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY property, stay_date ORDER BY added_timestamp) AS secondTimeStamp
```

You can put `LEAD` in your main query and you can remove `ROW_NUMBER` if you don't need it elsewhere.

```
SELECT  att.property, att.stayDate, att.addedTimeStamp, att.rowNumber, att.secondTimeStamp
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  RIGHT('000' + CAST(att.property AS VARCHAR(4)),4) AS property,
            CAST(att.stay_date AS DATE) AS stayDate,
            CAST(added_timestamp AS DATETIME) AS addedTimeStamp,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (PARTITION BY property, stay_date ORDER BY added_timestamp) AS rowNumber,

            LEAD(added_timestamp) OVER 
                (PARTITION BY property, stay_date ORDER BY added_timestamp) AS secondTimeStamp

        FROM dbo.tb_rm_portal_attention_days att
            WHERE att.revenue_initiative = 'Test'
    ) att
```